# Can waypoints (outposts, shelters, etc) appear underground?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was exploring a moon last night - had some luck finding scanners and oberservatories, so I had lots of locations pinging in my HUD to go visit.

However, at least two of these sites seemed to be underground (should have gotten a screenshot, sorry).

I parked my ship as close to the marker as possible, jumped out, and there's nothing there... I jumped back in the ship and circled a bit - no structure (even though it was a monolith/ruin marker).

I figured it must be underground - but I couldn't see any cave openings nearby and couldn't be bothered with an extended spelunk. I have seen a couple of sites that are practically inside a cave, but only just on the edge of the cavemouth.

So - has anyone actually visited one of these things underground?

Comment: I've never seen a landmark underground. Is it possible on a small enough planet that its literally on the other side of the world?

Comment: I've had this happen a few times with monoliths, I am able to walk around the waypoint but nothing is there. I tried grenades at one of the spots but didn't find anything. It appears to be a bug.

Comment: Landmarks might not spawn underground, but special overworld resources can be buried. Just last night I was trying to figure out where a Knowledge Stone was located, and through triangulation I realized that a large but otherwise normal iron vein had spawned quite literally on top of it. I had to mine the iron away before I could activate the stone to learn a new alien word.

Comment: I have seen things get buried or morphed into stuff. Never completely buried but I find that very easy to believe on some planets with larger veins

Comment: Anecdotally i've had a ruin waypoint in the water and when I got there there was nothing. I've even scouted the deeps for finding an underwater cave. But nothing, the ruin was never to be found.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible. If you look you will notice every landmark you visit is located on a flat circular area of land.

When the game places these landmarks it doesn't just place the building/ruin/etc. by itself, it places that flat circle of land with it sitting roughly in the center. It's all part of the procedural generation used by the game.

What you might have been experiencing is a landmark on another planet. You might have scanned while in space and found something on the other planet. A simple way to check is to look at the waypoint and see if it says off-planet. If it isn't offplanet but very far away that might also be causing the issue.

Comment: hmm - I would watch the ETA trend to zero as I approached in the ship and land at about 0:01 and walk over... nothing... I guess, it could also be a bug where there is a marker but no actual site is spawned

Comment: Can you see waypoints on other planets and in space while roaming around on, we'll just call it "Planet A"? Maybe I just don't pay that much attention, but I thought you could only see them once you're in space.

Comment: @C-dizzle Yes if you scan while in space and find something on planet B but you landed on Planet A the waypoint will show up, but instead of an arrival time it will just say "off-planet". I've also noticed it happen with space anomalies if there is one in the system and I haven't visited it yet

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with the game, the answer is most likely no. I have yet to encounter an underground outpost, and while that would be pretty cool, I don't think the developers intended for it to happen. It is most likely a glitch; I have run into this myself, where I fly to a location, but nothing is actually there. It has only happened for locations marked with a "?". Anything I find from a scanning station is a real, visible location.

Contrary to VanBuzzKill, I don't think you are seeing landmarks for other planets. Once you have flown to a specific planet, you will only see markers for that planet. Things on other planets, like transmissions or distress signals, may still show, but local locations/space stations will not.

The game is still in its early stages, and with patches with unknown fixes in them coming in the next few weeks, there may be resolutions to bugs such as these.

The one exception to this could be when outposts are placed underwater. While not technically underground, they still require you to go below the surface to activate them.

*Unfortunately I do not have concrete sources for this, other than my own experiences with the game.*

Answer (score 2):

I have seen semi-underground buildings. In fact I have seen moving it from the ground downwards. It was on top of a mountain. When I came into sight range I first had seen it on top but it was then jumping down into a cave. The top was still reaching out but the entrance was down in the cave, which was easy to see and reach since it was the top of the mountain.

I'd clearly consider this a bug. The building was hanging mostly in the air and some resources were reaching through the floor.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's  apparently a bug, especially with base missions from Foundation and with results of signal amplifier. No fix known.. if it's outpost or miner from Foundation quest, simply move to other planet

Comment: What exactly is the bug?

Comment: This question predates the Foundation update..

Comment: @HorusKol  I know that it does, but Foundation makes it a showstopper bug, because it is easily reproducible